# PDFium, extracted image inside pdf corrupted but when render no problem

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, .net-core, pdfium

I want to extract images in pdf and when I get raw bytes image is corrupted with "No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found".
I wrote bytes in file and test with windows image viewer and image magic and still corrupted. but any pdf viewer can show it. and even I can get rendered bitmap out of it with pdfium.

```
public byte[] GetImageRaw()
{
    var meta = FPdfLib.Instance.PageImageObject_GetImageMetaData(handle, pageHandle);
    var size = meta.width * meta.height * meta.bits_per_pixel / 8;
    return FPdfLib.Instance.PageImageObject_GetImageDataRaw(handle, (int)size); // implemented down 
}

public byte[] PageImageObject_GetImageDataRaw(IntPtr pageImageObject, int bufferSize)
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        var size = (int)FPdf.FPDFImageObj_GetImageDataRaw(pageImageObject, buffer, (ulong)bufferSize); // implemented down 
        var data = size == bufferSize ? buffer : buffer[..size];
        return data;
    }
}

// Get the raw image data of |image_object|. The raw data is the image data as
// stored in the PDF without applying any filters. |buffer| is only modified if
// |buflen| is longer than the length of the raw image data.
//
//   image_object - handle to an image object.
//   buffer       - buffer for holding the raw image data.
//   buflen       - length of the buffer in bytes.
//
// Returns the length of the raw image data.
[DllImport("pdfium.dll")]
public static extern ulong FPDFImageObj_GetImageDataRaw(FPDF_PAGEOBJECT image_object, byte[] buffer, ulong buflen);
```

Other images in pdf can be extracted with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

`FPDFImageObj_GetImageDataRaw` is raw, compressed image data as it is stored in the PDF stream itself. This method is useful for manipulating pdf document objects, but not so useful if you just want to extract the image data.

Use `FPDFImageObj_GetImageDataDecoded`, `FPDFImageObj_GetRenderedBitmap`, or `FPDFImageObj_SetBitmap` instead.

Note that for any of these methods you still need to add your own bitmap header for it to be a valid bitmap file.

Reference: https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/refs/heads/main/public/fpdf_edit.h